# Can you turn off scrolling in Chrome devtools DOM tree list

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I don't know if this is new in the latest version or if I've only just noticed it, but the scrolling of the list of DOM tree elements at the bottom of the Elements panel is driving me up the wall.

This feels utterly ridiculous to bring up but I can't even search effectively because I don't know what that part of the panel is officially called - and none of the preferences or experiments seem to relate to it.

So does anybody know how to turn this off?

[image: screenshot of chrome devtools with the bar at bottom of elements panel highlighted]

Comment: It's called the _breadcrumb bar_: https://umaar.com/dev-tips/52-better-breadcrumbs/

Comment: At least I know what it's called now! Thanks.

Comment: In response to your question: there is no built-in option in Chrome to disable the DOM breadcrumb bar nor alter its behaviour, but you can write a simple Chrome DevTools Extension that would be able to manipulate it.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the answer....

Comment: Looks like you've got a new weekend project then, eh?

Comment: It looks like this may be [removed in Chrome 108](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1369734) 