# Chrome dev tools : what is the scrolling bar at the bottom of the elements pane and how do I turn it off?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image: The image below shows what I'm talking about. It's the red text at the bottom and it scrolls right to left.]

The image below shows what I'm talking about. It's the red text at the bottom and it scrolls right to left.  It's distracting and I want to remove it, but I don't see how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is breadcrumbs i.e. the nesting path from the root (html) down to the current element. It can't be disabled.

Comment: That's nasty!  Filing bug report.

Comment: There's no option to hide it currently. As wOxxOm mentioned, it's a breadcrumb. What is the thing that make you feel distracted? e.g. Taking too many space, scrolling, etc

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73943485/450127

Comment: The scrolling motion.  If it just displayed the deepest spot in the breadcrumb flush right it wouldn't be a big deal.